# pdflatex: How do I print the help of a \PackageError or \ClassError text in non-interactive mode?

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling

I run miktex's `pdflatex` using `latexmk` in a non-intaractive mode (`-interaction=errorstopmode` or `-interaction=nonstopmode`) (often calling it from make, etc).
If an error occurs I get:

```
Class XXX Error: <Error Text>

See the XXX class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
```

and depending on the mode `pdflatex` continues or stops without printing the additional help. Is there a way to also print the additional help?

Google didn't help much. The only hint I found was to use interactive mode (which I don't want to do).

I found out that these messages are triggered by `\GenericError` from the latex2e kernel [macros2e](https://ctan.net/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf) via `\ClassError`  or`\PackageError`. Unfortunately the help of `\GenericError` limited to:

> Print error message to log file followed by the ‘further information’ line.  The help text is displayed if the user presses ‘h’.

Looking into the `latex2e` sources it seems like it the help text is forwarded to `\errhelp` [source](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/base/lterror.dtx#L197). Searching miktex's sources brought me to [pdftex.web](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/blob/next/Programs/TeXAndFriends/pdftex/source/pdftex.web), which says

```
@ If \.{\\errmessage} occurs often in |scroll_mode|, without user-defined
\.{\\errhelp}, we don't want to give a long help message each time. So we
give a verbose explanation only once.
```

This suggests that I should see a long message at least once. But that does not seem to happen. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to turn this on? I used my own `\PackageError` to ensure that the help isn't actually printed.

Comment: the interaction and printing of help texts is controlled by the underlying tex system it is not something that is written in the latex sources.

Comment: in interactive mode you get the help by typing h in the other modes it is always printed.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have to do anything. In batch mode the help text is logged always.

This is texlive but miktex should be the same.

test doc:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\PackageError{zzzz}{Main text}{help text}

\end{document}
```

run in batch mode, the terminal shows:

```
$ pdflatex --interaction=batchmode cc869
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

ie no interaction and no output, but the log shows

```
! Package zzzz Error: Main text.

See the zzzz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \PackageError{zzzz}{Main text}{help text}

help text
```

That is, the help text is shown at the point the `?` prompt would appear in interactive mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `\PackageError` to show also the third argument (the detailed error) in the first part of the output in the terminal. The third argument to `\GenericError` can be changed into a space character to prevent printing the detailed error twice in the log file (there will be an extra line with that space in it though).

Note that this might be confusing when you compile in normal mode, because you will be prompted to press `H` but then no additional help will be shown.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\PackageError#1#2#3{\GenericError{(#1)\@spaces \@spaces \@spaces \@spaces }{Package #1 Error: #2}{See the #1 package documentation for explanation. Detailed error: #3}{ }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
abc
\PackageError{mypackage}{custom error}{more detailed description}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
$ pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode myfile.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./myfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./myfile.aux)

! Package mypackage Error: custom error.

See the mypackage package documentation for explanation. Detailed error: more d
etailed description
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 ...e}{custom error}{more detailed description}

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./myfile.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on myfile.pdf (1 page, 10201 bytes).
Transcript written on myfile.log.
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited to remove the duplicate message from the log file.

Comment: thanks so I deleted initial comment, but I think that the actual answer is that the OP was simply incorrect and didn't notice that the help text is always printed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are probably right, however in `nonstopmode` the extra help is indeed not printed in the terminal, only in the log file - if for some reason the OP is looking at the terminal output only (maybe redirected somewhere, or from a remote connection where the terminal output is shown always but the log files are harder to check or something) then using something like this answer may be useful.